# How to create a simple user interface to declare variables?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on my first java project, one that simulates the behaviour of a neutrophil catching a bacterium (So random/semirandom particle behaviour). At the beginning of this program I have several variables (such as the radii of the organisms, etc) and right now they are fixed to the value I hardcoded in there. I want to create a user interface so that before the program starts, a screen pops up in which you can type in the values you want to use, and it uses those to run to program. Now I have used a swing script to create such a window and that looks a bit like this:

[image]

Now I'm wondering how I could implement it such that I can take the values used in those text boxes and assign them to my variables in my program.
This is the program I am referring to:

```
package nanocourse;

import java.awt.Color;
import nano.*;
import java.util.Random;
import prescreen.PreScreen;

public class Exercise3_final {

    public Exercise3_final() {

        int xSize = 1000;
        int ySize = 800;
        Canvas myScreen = new Canvas(xSize, ySize);
        Pen myPen = new Pen(myScreen);
        Random random = new Random();
        int frame=0; //how many frames have passed since start program

        //properties bacterium
        int xPosBacterium=random.nextInt(xSize); //random starting position of bacterium
        int yPosBacterium=random.nextInt(ySize);
        int K=1000; //how many points used to draw bacterium
        double [] xValueBacterium = new double[K]; //
        double [] yValueBacterium = new double[K]; 
        double bacteriumRadiusInput=20;
        double bacteriumRadius=bacteriumRadiusInput; //radius of bacterium
        boolean bacteriumAlive=true;

        //properties biomolecules
        int amountBio=30000;
        boolean [] bioExist = new boolean[amountBio];
        int [] xPosBio = new int [amountBio];
        int [] yPosBio = new int [amountBio];
        int [] dXBio = new int [amountBio];
        int [] dYBio = new int [amountBio];
        int [] lifetimeBio = new int [amountBio];
        double chanceDegrade=0.1; //chance that a biomolecule gets degraded per frame
        double chanceSynthesize=100; //chance that a biomolecule gets synthesized per frame
        for(int i=0;i<amountBio;i++) 
        {
            bioExist[i]=false; //setting existing state to false
        }

        //properties Neutrophil
        int xPosNeutrophil=random.nextInt(xSize);
        int yPosNeutrophil=random.nextInt(ySize);
        int L=1000;
        double [] xValueNeutrophil= new double[L];
        double [] yValueNeutrophil= new double[L];
        double neutrophilRadius=40;

        double xVector, yVector, xNormVector,yNormVector,magnitude,xSumVector,ySumVector;
        double aggressiveness=1;

        while(bacteriumAlive==true) //while program is running
            {
                frame++;
                //1. Simulating a moving Bacterium

                int dXBacterium=random.nextInt(11)-5; //random motion
                int dYBacterium=random.nextInt(11)-5;
                xPosBacterium=xPosBacterium+dXBacterium;
                yPosBacterium=yPosBacterium+dYBacterium;

                if(xPosBacterium<(bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize())) //boundaries bacterium,accounting for size bacterium
                {
                    xPosBacterium=(int)bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize();
                }
                else if(xPosBacterium>xSize - (bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize()))
                {
                    xPosBacterium=xSize - ((int)bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize());
                }
                else if(yPosBacterium<(bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize()))
                {
                    yPosBacterium=((int)bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize());
                }
                else if(yPosBacterium>ySize - (bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize()))
                {
                    yPosBacterium=ySize - ((int)bacteriumRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize());
                }



                //2. Simulating synthesis and secretion of biomolecules by the bacterium.
                for(int i=0;i<amountBio;i++)
                {    
                    double synthesizeNumber=Math.random()*100; 
                        if(synthesizeNumber<chanceSynthesize && i==frame)
                        {
                            bioExist[frame]=true; //make the  biomolecules exist 
                        }


                    if(bioExist[i]==true && frame!=1) //if biomolecule exist apply motion
                    {
                        dXBio[i]=random.nextInt(41)-20; 
                        dYBio[i]=random.nextInt(41)-20;
                        xPosBio[i]=xPosBio[i]+dXBio[i];
                        yPosBio[i]=yPosBio[i]+dYBio[i];
                    }
                    else  //if biomolecule doesn't exist, make position equal bacterium position
                    {
                        xPosBio[i]=xPosBacterium;
                        yPosBio[i]=yPosBacterium;
                    }

                    if(xPosBio[i]>xSize) //boundaries biomolecules
                    {
                        xPosBio[i]=xSize;
                    }
                    if(xPosBio[i]<0)
                    {
                        xPosBio[i]=0;
                    }
                    if(yPosBio[i]>ySize)
                    {
                        yPosBio[i]=ySize;
                    }
                    if(yPosBio[i]<0)
                    {
                        yPosBio[i]=0;
                    }

                    if(bioExist[i]==true)
                    {
                        lifetimeBio[i]++;
                        double degradationNumber=Math.random()*100;
                        if(degradationNumber<chanceDegrade)
                        {
                            bioExist[i]=false;
                        }
                    }

                    if(bioExist[i]==true && lifetimeBio[i]<=100) //if biomolecule lives shorter than 100 frames==>green
                    {
                        myPen.setColor(Color.GREEN); //drawing biomolecules
                        myPen.setShape(Shape.CIRCLE);
                        myPen.setSize(5);
                    }
                    if(bioExist[i]==true && (lifetimeBio[i]>100 && lifetimeBio[i]<=500)) //if biomolecule lives 101-500 frames==>green
                    {
                        myPen.setColor(Color.yellow); //drawing biomolecules
                        myPen.setShape(Shape.CIRCLE);
                        myPen.setSize(5);
                    }
                    if(bioExist[i]==true && (lifetimeBio[i]>500 && lifetimeBio[i]<=1000)) //if biomolecule lives 501-1000 frames==>orange
                    {
                        myPen.setColor(Color.ORANGE); //drawing biomolecules
                        myPen.setShape(Shape.CIRCLE);
                        myPen.setSize(5);
                    }
                    if(bioExist[i]==true && (lifetimeBio[i]>1000 && lifetimeBio[i]<=1500)) //if biomolecule lives 1001-1500 frames==>red
                    {
                        myPen.setColor(Color.RED); //drawing biomolecules
                        myPen.setShape(Shape.CIRCLE);
                        myPen.setSize(5);
                    }
                    if(bioExist[i]==true && lifetimeBio[i]>1500) //if biomolecule lives 2001+ frames==>magenta
                    {
                        myPen.setColor(Color.magenta); //drawing biomolecules
                        myPen.setShape(Shape.CIRCLE);
                        myPen.setSize(5);
                    }
                    if(bioExist[i]==true)
                    {
                        myPen.draw(xPosBio[i],yPosBio[i]);
                    }
                    if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(xPosBio[i]-xPosNeutrophil),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(yPosBio[i]-yPosNeutrophil), 2))<neutrophilRadius)
                    {
                        bioExist[i]=false; //degrade if inside neutrophil
                    }
                }
                if(bacteriumAlive==true)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i <K ; i++) //defining circle, drawing points, placed here because it needs to be on top
                    { 
                        xValueBacterium[i] = bacteriumRadius*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/K); 
                        yValueBacterium[i] = bacteriumRadius*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/K);
                        myPen.setColor(Color.red);
                        myPen.setShape(Shape.CIRCLE);
                        myPen.setSize(5);
                        myPen.draw((int)xValueBacterium[i]+xPosBacterium,(int)yValueBacterium[i]+yPosBacterium);
                    }
                }
                //5. Simulating the neutrophil eating the bacteriun

                xSumVector=0;
                ySumVector=0;
                for(int i=0;i<amountBio;i++)
                {
                    if(Math.abs(xPosBio[i]-xPosNeutrophil)<(30+neutrophilRadius) && Math.abs(yPosBio[i]-yPosNeutrophil)<(30+neutrophilRadius) && bioExist[i]==true)
                    {
                            xVector=xPosBio[i]-xPosNeutrophil;
                            yVector=yPosBio[i]-yPosNeutrophil;
                            magnitude=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xVector, 2)+Math.pow(yVector, 2));
                            xNormVector=xVector/magnitude;
                            yNormVector=yVector/magnitude;
                            xSumVector=xSumVector+xNormVector;
                            ySumVector=ySumVector+yNormVector;

                    }
                }

                //3. Simulating a moving neutrophil
                int dXNeutrophil=random.nextInt(11)-5+(int)aggressiveness*(int)xSumVector; //random motion
                int dYNeutrophil=random.nextInt(11)-5+(int)aggressiveness*(int)ySumVector;
                xPosNeutrophil=xPosNeutrophil+dXNeutrophil;
                yPosNeutrophil=yPosNeutrophil+dYNeutrophil;

                myPen.setSize(8);
                if(xPosNeutrophil<(neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize())) //boundaries neutrophil
                {
                    xPosNeutrophil=(int)neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize();
                }
                else if(xPosNeutrophil>xSize - (neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize()))
                {
                    xPosNeutrophil=xSize - ((int)neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize());
                }
                else if(yPosNeutrophil<(neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize()))
                {
                    yPosNeutrophil=((int)neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize());
                }
                else if(yPosNeutrophil>ySize - (neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize()))
                {
                    yPosNeutrophil=ySize - ((int)neutrophilRadius/2+2*myPen.getSize());
                }
                for(int i = 0; i <L ; i++) //defining circle, drawing points, placed here because it needs to be on top
                { 
                    xValueNeutrophil[i] = neutrophilRadius*Math.cos(2*Math.PI*i/L); 
                    yValueNeutrophil[i] = neutrophilRadius*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/L);
                    myPen.setColor(Color.blue);
                    myPen.setShape(Shape.CIRCLE);
                    myPen.draw((int)xValueNeutrophil[i]+xPosNeutrophil,(int)yValueNeutrophil[i]+yPosNeutrophil);
                }

                if(Math.abs(xPosNeutrophil-xPosBacterium)<2*bacteriumRadiusInput && Math.abs(yPosNeutrophil-yPosBacterium)<2*bacteriumRadiusInput && bacteriumRadius >=0)
                {
                    bacteriumRadius=bacteriumRadius-1;
                    if(bacteriumRadius==0)
                    {
                        bacteriumAlive=false;
                    }
                }

                if(bacteriumAlive==false)
                {
                    bacteriumAlive=true;
                    xPosBacterium=random.nextInt(xSize); //random starting position of bacterium
                    yPosBacterium=random.nextInt(ySize);
                    bacteriumRadius=bacteriumRadiusInput;
                }
                myScreen.update(); //updating/refreshing screen
                myScreen.pause(10);
                myScreen.clear();
            }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise3_final e = new Exercise3_final();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd make a class that stores values for all those parameters.  Then the UI could instantiate that class based on the values of the fields, and pass the resulting object to a method of the calculation engine.  You'll need to use the `getText()` method of the class that you've used for your text fields, along with the `parseDouble()` static method of the `Double` class and probably the `parseInt()` static method of the `Integer` class.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Given those values seem to be numeric, I would recommend using spinners (`JSpinner`) with a `SpinnerNumberModel` instead of a text field. Keep a reference to the models and use `numberModel.getNumber.intValue()` for an integer number. The number model can have a default value, meaning the `Use Default Settings` check box becomes redundant. Add an `ActionListener` to the `Run!` button, and when it's activated, close that screen, get the numbers from the models and begin the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an action listener on the "Run!" button from your dialog:

```
_run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // set the variables here by getting the text from the inputs
    field1Var = Integer.parseInt(field1Input.getText());
    field2Var = Integer.parseInt(field2Input.getText());
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a singleton class to save all the values that are captured from the first screen (options menu screen).
You can get the instance of this class anywhere in the application later on and use it.
Advantages would be:
- You will not have to carry forward the values everywhere in the application.
- The values captured will the persisted till the application is shut down.

Note: Make sure to add validations while fetching values from the options menu so that incorrect values are not set.

Comment: Please don't do this. 
 For some of the reasons, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scottdensmore/2004/05/25/why-singletons-are-evil/ and http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/

Comment: while these are some good points against singleton classes, but every requirement is different and it can be achieved using various tools in java. The requirement here is not that complicated and one singleton class is not hard to handle here. The initialization of the singleton class should be linked with the menu here.